# How to change formatting of colorbar in combination with shrink

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a colorbar for my figure like this:

```
def fmt(x, pos):
    a='{:10.1f}'.format(x)
    return a

fig.colorbar(CS, ax=ax,shrink=0.35,label=r'Electric Field/(V/$\mathrm{\AA}$)',format=ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))
```

Creating the colorbar without the format command works just fine. However, I would like to control the number of decimal points in the colorbar labels. Adding the format command seems to not work in combination with shrink, since the labels are now shifted from the colorbar:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are shifting the labels away from the colorbar yourself. So if you don't want that don't do it.

I.e. Using `'{:10.1f}'.format(1)` you tell the formatter to use 10 places before the decimal separator. You may leave out the 10 to get it to only use as many places as it needs,

```
'{:.1f}'.format(1)
```

Comment: Wow, that was really a stupid moment by myself, thanks!!